# how can I filter the list for address > "country" field in "new individual"

Tags: addresses, individual, fieldoptions

I want to filter the option list of the "country" field on the address tab.. I found out that the country field is getting the list of country field in "civicrm_country" table and I want to add a new column "is_active" on the table for the filtering but I can't find the function that generates the list.. does someone know where I can find the function generating the option list so I can add the filter? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE, Could you please tell why you want to add 'is_active' field to country table? Can't you just disable the countries from appearing in drop down(or include only countries that you need in your system) from CiviCRM >> Administer >> Localization >> Languages, Currency, Locations?

Comment: oh... didn't know that there was such an option there, thanks a lot